# ORACLE - Update Multiple Columns with Values from Nested Join

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, subquery

I'm practically new in using oracle and I bumped into a blocker. Below is the query that I created based on what I have researched online to update multiple columns of a table with values from a nested join statement.

```
UPDATE
(    
    SELECT
    A.COLUMN1 OLD_COLUMN1,
    BC.COLUMN1 NEW_COLUMN1,
    A.BALANCE OLD_COLUMN2,
    BC.COLUMN2_MIN NEW_COLUMN2,
    A.COLUMN3 OLD_COLUMN3,
    BC.COLUMN3 NEW_COLUMN3
    FROM TABLE_A A
    INNER JOIN  
    (
        SELECT B.TWWID,
               B.ITEMDATE,
               B.COLUMN2_MIN,
               C.COLUMN3,
               C.COUNTRYID,
               C.COLUMN1 
        FROM TABLE_B B
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C C
            ON TO_CHAR(B.ID) = TO_CHAR(C.ID)
    ) BC
        ON A.ID = BC.ID
        AND A.DATE = BC.DATE
)ABCUPDATE
SET ABCUPDATE.OLD_COLUMN1 = ABCUPDATE.NEW_COLUMN1,
ABCUPDATE.OLD_COLUMN2 = ABCUPDATE.NEW_COLUMN2,
ABCUPDATE.OLD_COLUMN3 = ABCUPDATE.NEW_COLUMN3;
```

Selecting the sub-query returns the expected results but when I run the update script as a whole an error is returned.

> ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved
>   table

Can anyone please explain why I encounter this error and what adjustments can I do to the script to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01779_cannot_modify_a_column_which_maps_to_a_non_keypreserved_table.htm might help you. `Merge` would be the apt choice.

Comment: When you update through a join, the Oracle parser needs to know ahead of time (before seeing the data) that each row in the table you are updating references one row (not more) in the "other table" (in this case, the nested join view). This means that you must have the proper primary and foreign keys on the tables. Do you, in fact, have PK and FK defined on your tables?

Comment: Why are you casting your ID columns to strings? `TO_CHAR(B.ID) = TO_CHAR(C.ID)`????